# Nodejs "requiring" files from directory as modules . Confused about file-path prefix

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

I am trying to require some files into another file as modules . As a neophyte to the NodeJS I am somewhat perplexed as I thought require statements could only call upon modules defined in the modules directory !

```
Home>src>middleware> {:current file}
var UserModel = require('src/models/user');//`Home>src>models>user.js`
var userDAO = require('src/dao/user');//`Home>src>dao>user.js`
```

I have downloaded a "bootstrapped" version of HapiJS and having trouble getting started . Github '/sample-hapi-rest-api/' . I am not very experienced with NodeJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to require files is to use relative pathing. If your current file is in `Home>src>middleware>` then you want

```
var UserModel = require('../models/user');//`Home>src>models>user.js`
var userDAO = require('../dao/user');//`Home>src>dao>user.js`
```

Comment: Thank you ! Issue resolved . I am currently having the same types of errors throughout this code base I have . Could it be that the file paths are somehow dependent on the environment I am using ?

Comment: I can't say for sure without more information on what the exact error is.

Comment: You might see if this link helps: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2169-where-does-node-js-and-require-look-for-modules.htm

Comment: Excellent ! Thanks for the responses my friend . You have been very helpful !